# Unsorted Priority Queue

Tags: data-structures

I've been misguided a bit and so am a bit confused.This is what I have understood as an unsorted priority queue.Can someone please confirm?
An unsorted priority queue is one in which we insert at the end and remove elements based on priority(i,e; smallest value in the queue).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the basic queue in data structure works based on first come first serve (FIFO) first in first out,
the first element was inserted in the queue the one will be served or executed in the queue, and the last element will be served or executed last, this method represent unsorted queue.

for the sorted queue it will sort the inserted elements then execute them as your sorting method

if you added some kind of sorting algorithm attached to the queue it will work as the algorithm work.
for more info :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

The priority queue is an abstract data structure that defines the method get-min, push and pop-min, possibly also union. Whether the concrete implementation is using a sorted container or not should not affect the operations that we should be able to perform.

There are several possible implementations, most popular of which uses binary heap(that in a way is not sorted), but one way also use a sorted list for example. I think maybe wherever you heard about `unsorted priority queue` the person may have meant a priority queue that is not implemented using a sorted list or other sorted container.

Answer (score 1):

There is a conceptual difference between a Queue and a Priority Queue. A Queue is a first-in, first-out data structure that allows efficient access to both ends of the queue (head and tail). A Priority Queue is an *abstract* data structure that provides a getBestItem() function, without specificying how (hence *abstract*).

An Unsorted Priority Queue could refer to a PQ implementation that does no intermittent work (no organization of elements) and implements getBestItem() as a simple, linear search. This makes getBestItem() very inefficient (*O(n)*), but insert/delete very cheap (*O(1)*). If Insert/Delete is frequent and getBestItem() is not, this could be a valid choice.